# Deleting content of folder with shell script

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, command

Im having problems trying to empty a folder in my script.

This is working in my command line:

```
rm -r Folder1/Folder2/*
```

But if in my script I do this:

```
DIR="Folder1/Folder2/"
rm -r "$DIR*"
```

It says "rm: Folder1/Folder2/*: No such file or directory", where is the problem?

Im running the script in the same folder as I tried the command.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Glob expansion doesn't happen inside quotes.

Try:

```
rm -r -- "$DIR"*
```

(Just make really sure you don't put a space after the quotes.)

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -r $DIR*
```

That should work, without quotes

Comment: Not if `$DIR` has spaces in it.