# Why doesn't rm -rf $DIR delete the directory when run from a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to delete a directory referenced by an environment variable in my bash script, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DIR='~/.docker-volumes/mydir'

rm -rf ${DIR}
```

Following some suggestions in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61166/rm-fr-not-working and [Deleting content of folder with shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483678/deleting-content-of-folder-with-shell-script), I've also tried the following in my bash script to no avail:

```
rm -rf ${DIR}
find ${DIR} -type d -delete
rm -rf "$DIR"
echo $DIR | rm -rf
rm -rf -- "$DIR"
```

However, the directory pointed to by `$DIR` isn't deleted. I can delete it directly from my Mac terminal using `rm -rf ~/.docker-volumes/mydir` and it works as intended. The following also works from a bash script:

```
rm -rf ~/.docker-volumes/mydir
```

I don't like the above method though as I'd like to reference a variable, as the same path is needed in other places.

**Question:** Why do none of the above bash script commands which makes use of a variable, actually delete the directory? What do I need to do to delete the directory using a variable?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Could you please show the question this is potentially a duplicate of? The 'marked as duplicate' message does not mention it.

Comment: The UI is slightly confusing: look at the other yellow message right below the title

Comment: There should be two duplicates listed at the top of the question. In any case, the short answer is that `~` doesn't expand to your home directory when it's in quotes.

Comment: Thanks guys, got it. I was sure SO duplicates were mentioned as part of the section where it's marked a duplicate. Perhaps they've changed the UI.

Comment: I may be thinking of 'Possible duplicate of' instead of 'marked as duplicate' :)